# Setting custom user attribute in Keycloak plugin

Tags: java, plugins, keycloak

I'm writing w user Keycloak plugin. It listenes to events by implementing EventListenerProvider

On user registration it is supposed to create a default group for the new user and assign this user to the newly created group - works.
Moreover it shall attache a new attribute to user containing an ID of the newly created group - but after exacuting the following code I cannot see the created "default-organization" attribute in "attributes" tab for created user in Keycloak's admin console
[image]

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public CustomRegisterEventProvider(final KeycloakSession session) {

    this.session = session;
    this.model = session.realms();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onEvent(final Event event) {

    if (event.getType().equals(REGISTER)) {
        final RealmModel realm = this.model.getRealm(event.getRealmId());
        final String userId = event.getUserId();

        GroupModel organization = createDefaultOrgainzation(realm,
                "default-" + userId);
        joinOrganization(realm, userId, organization);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private GroupModel createDefaultOrgainzation(final RealmModel realm,
        final String name) {

    final GroupModel org = this.session.groups().createGroup(realm, name);
    org.setSingleAttribute("organization", "true");

    return org;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void joinOrganization(final RealmModel realm, final String userId,
        final GroupModel organization) {

    final UserModel user = this.session.users().getUserById(realm, userId);
    user.setSingleAttribute("default-organization", organization.getId());
    
    LOGGER.log(FINE, "Successfully assigned " + user.getAttributes().toString());
    user.joinGroup(organization); // this lines prints the  "default-organization" attribute with value - but admin console does not show it

    LOGGER.log(FINE, format("Successfully assigned user: %s, to %s", userId,
            organization.getName()));
}
```